# How can I check if the certificates in a p7b bundle are already in the local store

Tags: c#, x509certificate, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to connect to AWS DocumentDb using C# with TLS enabled.

The sample code reads that the certificates must be only added once to the local store, however it doesn't say how to check if the certificates are already installed.

If I have a p7b file and added it to the local store, how can I check if all those certificates in p7b file are already installed so I don't try to do it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can view local store certificate as below -

1. Go to Microsoft Management Console (mmc) (Start Menu to RUN, then type mmc and enter)
2. In Microsoft Management Console, Go to File and click on Add/Remove Snap-in.
3. In Available Snap-ins pane - select certificates and click add.

The Certificates snap-in allows you to browse the contents of the certificate stores for yourself, a service, or a computer.

4. As certificate is in Local Computer store, choose 'Computer Account' radio button, and next choose ‘Local Computer' and finally hit Finish.
5. Now you will return to Add or Remove Snap-Ins dialog box. In Selected snap-ins pane, you will see Console Root and Certificate (Local Computer) as a leaf.  Click OK.
6. Now you will reach to MMC console. On the left pane - under Console Root, you will see ‘Certificates’ option. Double Click on it.
7. A list will appear on middle pane, double click on ‘Trusted Root Certification Authorities’ and new folder will appear with name Certificates.
8. Double click on Certificate Folder to see all the certs.  There is also find certificate option in previous window to search the specific cert in certificate folder that you can also use.
9. You can also save current mmc console  using File and Save  so that later you can directly open it.

Answer (score 0):

The `X509Certificate2Collection` class has a method named [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.import?view=net-6.0) that can load PKCS#7 (which the *.p7b file is).
On the other hand there is the [`X509Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509store-ctor(system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-storename-system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-storelocation)) class, which allows to open a local certificate store. Both contain a list of their certificates. You can compare them using their Issuer/SerialNumber or public key.